# Jula REPL number formatting

Tags: julia

In MatLab/Octave you could send a command "[format long g](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html#inputarg_Style)" and have default numerical output in the REPL formatted like the following:

> octave> 95000/0.05
>
> ans = 1900000

Is it possible to get a similar behavior in Julia?  Currently with julia

> Version 0.3.0-prerelease+3930 (2014-06-28 17:54 UTC)
>
> Commit bdbab62* (6 days old master)
>
> x86_64-redhat-linux

I get the following number format.

> julia> 95000/0.05
>
> 1.9e6

Answer (score 6):

You can use the **@printf** macro to format.  It behaves like the C printf, but unlike printf for C the type need not agree but is rather converted as necessary.  For example

```
julia> using Printf
julia> @printf("Integer Format: %d",95000/0.05);
Integer Format: 1900000

julia> @printf("As a String: %s",95000/0.05);
As a String: 1.9e6

julia> @printf("As a float with column sized larger than needed:%11.2f",95000/0.05);
As a float with column sized larger than needed: 1900000.00
```

It is possible to use **@printf** as the default mechanism in the REPL because the REPL is implemented in Julia in Base.REPL, and in particular the following function:

```
function display(d::REPLDisplay, ::MIME"text/plain", x)
    io = outstream(d.repl)
    write(io, answer_color(d.repl))
    writemime(io, MIME("text/plain"), x)
    println(io)
end
```

To modify the way ***Float64*** is displayed, you merely need to redefine **writemime** for ***Float64***.

```
julia> 95000/0.05
1.9e6

julia> Base.Multimedia.writemime(stream,::MIME"text/plain",x::Float64)=@printf("%1.2f",x)
writemime (generic function with 13 methods)

julia> 95000/0.05
1900000.00
```

Comment: Just wondering, how do I print the numbers in scientific notation so that I can export the data onto LaTeX?

Comment: This sounds dangerous.